# Resource has been exhausted Google Cloud Speech

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am trying to transcribe a 45 min long audio file with google cloud speech but I keep getting

> Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)

I have the free credit that the api offers you for a year. Tried it in the api explorer and in python where I will be using it but the result is the same. This is the request I send:

```
{
 "audio": {
  "uri": "gs://speech_summarization/mq.3gp"
 },
 "config": {
  "encoding": "AMR",
  "sampleRate": 8000
 }
}
```

and response:

```
429

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "code": 429,
  "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
  "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
 }
}
```

I saw similar problems solved by cutting the video in shorter versions but with 10 min it didn't work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: The only free tier I can see from a web search is limited to 60 minutes per month. Note that is cumulative, so if you ran 10 minutes, 6x, even if it was the same file, you would have hit your quota.

Comment: You get 300 pounds worth free credit for a year when you register for the google cloud platform.

Comment: Has it ever worked for you on any file? I would triple check that you have entered your API key properly (no extra spaces or characters etc.)

Comment: Files under 1 min work well and I have enabled the API otherwise the error message would be different.

Answer (score 1):

Files under 1 minute are working because, in addition to an absolute quota on audio sent to the API there are specific limits on streams of audio:

https://cloud.google.com/speech/limits

I haven't had much luck finding a free version (even on trial) of transcription products like those offered by Nuance.

Comment: As far as I understand I am inside the limits provided. I am using Asynchronous Requests which can transcribe audio up to 80 min long with uri attribute that I am using.

Comment: Changing the encoding helped! Thank you for your suggestions anyway.